# Modify a character's rotation without altering it's movement

Tags: unity, scripting

I have a character that moves around using a virtual joystick on screen (mobile game joystick) however the player doesn't face forward to the position the joystick is pointing. Whenever I modify the rotation values on script it goes off the rails and moves erratically. What can I do to achieve this movement without altering it's translation?

Here is my script:

```
     void Update()
{


    horizontal = inputJoystick.horizontal();
    vertical = inputJoystick.vertical();

    moveDirection = new Vector3(horizontal, 0, vertical);
    moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
    moveDirection *= speed;

    //rotationDirection = new Vector3(horizontal, 0, vertical);
    //transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(rotationDirection, Vector3.up);
    controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now when you rotate the mesh you interfere with the movement because `transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection)` transforms from local to world space, so your move direction ends up depending on more than just the joystick's direction and as you rotate the mesh it will change. You need to keep this transform stable.

You can use a game object hierarchy like:

```
Controller
-- Mesh
```

And attach to the Controller all your movement-related components, including something like `CharacterMovementScript`, and to the Mesh attach the rotating component `CharacterRotateScript`.

```
public class CharacterMovementScript : MonoBehaviour {

    void Update () {
        var horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        var vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        var moveDirection = new Vector3(horizontal, 0, vertical);
        moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
        moveDirection *= 1.0f;

        var controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}

public class CharacterRotateScript : MonoBehaviour {

    void Update () {
        var horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        var vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        if (horizontal != 0.0f || vertical != 0.0f) {
            var rotationDirection = new Vector3(horizontal, 0, vertical);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(rotationDirection, Vector3.up);
        }
    }
}
```

Doing this should get you closer to what you're looking for, I think.